# Как изменить Настройки поля редактора кода?

Tags: swift, xcode

Скажите пожалуйста, где меняются Настройки поля редактора кода? Дело в том что у меня была проблема, для решения которой я лазил в настройках и теперь в строках перед кодом идут серые точки, Код берётся в небольшие серые скобки - они не на что не влияют, но...капец как раздражают‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы говорите об invisible symbols:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы их убрать выберите Editor -> Hide invisibles.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Просто как?! Почему когда заходишь в верхнюю панель, перепробовываешь все - и не находишь, а оно там есть все таки... ))